# How to make Joomla Form Field SQL Empty Value at start

Tags: joomla3.0

I'm trying to make a drop down menu for the Country field in Joomla User profile.

```
<field name="countries" type="sql" label="Country" query="SELECT id, country_name FROM #__countries" key_field="id" value_field="country_name" required="true"/>
```

How can i make this 'Empty Value' at start and let the user to select? is it possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

```
<field name="countries" type="sql" label="Country" query="SELECT id, country_name FROM #__countries" key_field="id" value_field="country_name" required="true" default="0">
  <option value="0">Empty</option>
</field>
```

Comment: While Answering please try to add explanation for your code

Answer (score 1):

```
<field name="countries" type="sql" label="Country" query="SELECT 0 AS `id`, '- Please select country -' AS `country_name` UNION SELECT id, country_name FROM #__countries" key_field="id" value_field="country_name" required="true"/>
```